# Replace variable having backslach

Tags: java, regex, replace, backslash

The purpose of code is to replace value by another value for a configuration file.

The old value is assigned to a variable **oldValue**="serverip=http://82.347.34.12"

The new value is assigned to another variable **newValue**="serverip=http://99.347.34.12"

```
void searchFile(File nameOfFile, String oldValue, String newValue) throws IOException {
    try {

                System.out.println("Old setting: " + lines); // returns -> serverip=http:\/\/82.347.34.12
                System.out.println("New setting: " + settingToApply); // returns --> serverip=http:\/\/99.347.34.12

                Path path = Paths.get(SETTINGS);
                Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

                String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);

                // changes any cases correctly except when value have \
                content = content.replaceAll(oldValue, newValue); 
                Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));

        }

        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // handle this
    }
}
```

}

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.replaceAll` takes a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). You will either have to escape regex special characters (e.g. slashes) or use `String.replace`, which doesn't take a regex.